# How does detective Kagami's sister get killed?

Tags: ranpo-kitan

How does detective Kagami's sister get killed? And I guess I'm looking for specifics, like did the killer break her legs, etc? From what I saw, her body was dangling, and it looked as if her arms were cut off.